# on submit click button enable next tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we having three tabs initially first tabs should enabled i's working fine. after click submit button second tab should be open but it's is not working.

```
$("#myTabs form").on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkHref=$(this).parents('.tab-pane').attr('id');
    $('#myLinks li')
        .find('a[href="#'+linkHref+'"]')
        .parent()
        .next()
        .find('a').tab('show')
        .attr('data-toggle','tab');
});
```

Demo link: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/aLffebsy/3/)

Comment: its like the second tab lose his event suscribed

Comment: Did you try target: _blank attribute in HTML?

Comment: no @ProgrammingEnthusiast....

Comment: yes correct @HenriqueYC.

Comment: in some issues we have to re-suscribe all events on this eviroment that hapen in many frameworks

Comment: first your HTMLs is not correctly formatted and then .tab function is undefined, and generally I think you made it unnecessarily too complex . you could have it done much simpler .

Comment: ok sir any reference code give me sir @nullqube

Comment: <a href="URLaddress" target="_blank">URL Address Name</a> Will open the link in a new tab

Comment: if you OK with jquery UI then take a look at this pen https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK or http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Tabs-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/  or  http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best but give you some idea :

```js
function go(tab,content, cityName) {
    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    $('.tabcontent.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.tablinks.active').removeClass('active');
    tab.addClass('active');
    content.addClass('active');
}

$(function(){
  $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    go($('#tab-2'),$('.tablinks:contains("Tab2")'),'tab-2');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

div.tabcontent.active {
  display:block;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active">Tab1</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Tab2</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Tab3</button>
</div>

<div id="tab-1" class="tabcontent active">
  <form id="form" action="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" action ="">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab2</h3>
  <p>...</p> 
</div>

<div id="tab-3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab3</h3>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```